# ListPicker - how to make current selection show when full page view opens

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit, listpicker

I'm using the ListPicker from the latest Silverlight Toolkit on Mango

I've got a long list (100 items) of simple text items to choose between - using single item selection mode.

When I click on the ListPicker it opens up in full screen very nicely, but it doesn't scroll to the current selection.

This is a pain for the user - who typically wants to move from "item75" to "item76"

I've looked through the available properties, events and source code, but I can't see any obvious way to get the list to scroll the current selected item into list when the full screen mode opens.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: I see the previously selected item in the middle of the list when I reopen it. This is using the Feb toolkit on NoDo. What are you using? and how are you binding the items & selecteditem?

Comment: Hi Matt - I'm on 1.4.6 on Mango (actually using Mango APIs too!). All items are added in code using simple strings - and selected item set similarly. Using the "Phone Toolkit Sample" downloaded from the marketplace I see the same behaviour there with selected items (e.g. try the long colour list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There didn't seem to be a way to do this with the current release - but the code is open source.

The current release also has a disadvantage of using StackPanel instead of VirtualizingStackPanel - so it is very slow at displaying long lists.

Instead of using this release, I ended up going with a different list selector http://priyarules.posterous.com/categorized-list-selector-for-windows-phone-7

Answer (score 1):

I found this Which may help, i hope it does! 
[in Depth ListPicker](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/listpicker-for-wp7-in-depth)

See on MSDN what some of the events that can be triggered when selecting a Listpicker item and mess around with them, you may find a Very good Solution! :)